# Where store User Settings iOS - App Store

Tags: ios, sqlite, app-store

in the message of the resolution center (App Store) I received the following message:
"The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., may be stored in the /Documents directory - and backed up by iCloud.".

In my iOS application I store the "Settings" in a SQLite file. That I create just one time and gets modified by the user when he requires to do those changes. The size of this file is about 20kb and I'm storing it in Documents (as Critical Data). It is correct to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. If you reply to them and tell them what you've said above, they'll probably allow you to pass the review. Just make it clear that it's user created/modified and needs to be backed up.

Source: This happened to us as well and we challenged and got accepted.

Note: You could save settings in the NSUserDefaults instead if you don't want to have to challenge them.

Comment: I was about to reccomend NSUserDefaults until I saw the line mentioning the file was 20kb big. I don't think that'd be particularly efficient to store in NSUserDefaults, that's for small things, not large data